# WPF ScrollViewer for control

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I have an issue with ScrollViewer. Here is the code:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbFrom" Text="MailSendTo=Send to:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,3"/>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <util:ctlStaffPicker x:Name="ctlStaffPicker1" ForMessaging="True" TabIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  MaxHeight="75"></util:ctlStaffPicker>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,5" Height="70">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="tbQuickMessage" Text="LBLQuickMessage=Quick Message:" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,3"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtQuickMessage"
                MaxHeight="35"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Text="{Binding MessageText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ctlNewMessage}}}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                TabIndex="1" />
    </StackPanel>
```

I know that a ScrollViewer inside StackPanel will never work fine. I want to make scrollable just `<util:ctlStaffPicker>`. Could you please help with some suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Here is small screenshot of the different scroller appearances, the second one is the classic one:
[image: different scroller appearances]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an internal `Grid Panel` instead:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbFrom" Text="MailSendTo=Send to:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,3"/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <util:ctlStaffPicker x:Name="ctlStaffPicker1" ForMessaging="True" TabIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  MaxHeight="75"></util:ctlStaffPicker>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,5" Height="70">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="tbQuickMessage" Text="LBLQuickMessage=Quick Message:" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,3"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtQuickMessage"
                MaxHeight="35"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Text="{Binding MessageText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ctlNewMessage}}}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                TabIndex="1" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Please note that `StackPanel`s should only be used for the simplest layout duties.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The scroller that appears, looks strange (with no arrows), not like the classic one. Is there a way to correct it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question so that we can see?

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question, where the first scroll is the strange one, the second is the classic one.

Comment: There is only one image uploaded.

Comment: Yes, on the image are both scrolls - the first one with no arrows (which is the result from your answer, and the second one with arrows (a scroll of the TextBox)

Comment: Ahhh... those arrows are only shown when there is not enough space to display the scroll bar... you can just increase the height to see the scroll bar.

Comment: You mean to increase the height of ScrollViewer, right?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I mean.